# How to use Laravel to promote students from one grade to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a raw php code which promote students from one grade to another upon a submission and it works fine. I want to use Laravel to do that and I seem not to get it. I need assistance and to learn from it.

```
public function updateClass() {

    $QueryStudent  = "
    UPDATE students
    SET CurrentClass = (
    CASE CurrentClass
      WHEN 'Grade 1' THEN 'Grade 2'
      WHEN 'Grade 2' THEN 'Grade 3'                                               
      WHEN 'Grade 3' THEN 'Grade 4'                                                  
      WHEN 'Grade 4' THEN 'Grade 5'                                                     
      WHEN 'Grade 5' THEN 'Grade 6'                                                                                                                                            
      WHEN 'Grade 6' THEN 'Graduate'                                         
    END
    )
    WHERE CurrentClass IN ('Grade 1', 'Grade 2', 'Grade 3', 'Grade 4', 'Grade 5', 'Grade 6')";

    $StudentStmt = $Connection->query($QueryStudent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use  statement method:

```
    DB::statement("    
        UPDATE students
        SET CurrentClass = (
        CASE CurrentClass
          WHEN 'Grade 1' THEN 'Grade 2'
          WHEN 'Grade 2' THEN 'Grade 3'
          WHEN 'Grade 3' THEN 'Grade 4'
          WHEN 'Grade 4' THEN 'Grade 5'
          WHEN 'Grade 5' THEN 'Grade 6'
          WHEN 'Grade 6' THEN 'Graduate'
        END
        )
        WHERE CurrentClass IN ('Grade 1', 'Grade 2', 'Grade 3', 'Grade 4', 'Grade 5', 'Grade 6')
     ");
```

This will update all the records in the table `students`. Don't forget to add this line before the class definition :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

if you want to update particular record by id you need to combine the statements method with the raw method:

```
    DB::statement(
        DB::raw("
            UPDATE students
            SET CurrentClass = (
            CASE CurrentClass
              WHEN 'Grade 1' THEN 'Grade 2'
              WHEN 'Grade 2' THEN 'Grade 3'
              WHEN 'Grade 3' THEN 'Grade 4'
              WHEN 'Grade 4' THEN 'Grade 5'
              WHEN 'Grade 5' THEN 'Grade 6'
              WHEN 'Grade 6' THEN 'Graduate'
            END
            )
            WHERE 
                  id = ? AND
                  CurrentClass IN ('Grade 1', 'Grade 2', 'Grade 3', 'Grade 4', 'Grade 5', 'Grade 6')
            "),
        array($user_id)
    );
```

UPDATE: according to [lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) comments I've removed DB::raw :

```
    DB::statement(
        "
            UPDATE students
            SET CurrentClass = (
            CASE CurrentClass
              WHEN 'Grade 1' THEN 'Grade 2'
              WHEN 'Grade 2' THEN 'Grade 3'
              WHEN 'Grade 3' THEN 'Grade 4'
              WHEN 'Grade 4' THEN 'Grade 5'
              WHEN 'Grade 5' THEN 'Grade 6'
              WHEN 'Grade 6' THEN 'Graduate'
            END
            )
            WHERE
                  id = ? AND
                  CurrentClass IN ('Grade 1', 'Grade 2', 'Grade 3', 'Grade 4', 'Grade 5', 'Grade 6')
            ",
        array($user_id)
    );
```

Comment: `statement` is raw already, you don't need `DB::raw`

Comment: Yes, statement is raw, but you can't bind parameter with it. I added DB::raw to use PDO parameter binding and protect the query from the sql injection

Comment: you don't need `DB::raw` ... `DB::statement` is a raw statement already; its not query builder ... `DB::raw` is redundant here

Comment: I checked and found that DB::statement accepts binded parameters as well, so I've updated the answer according to your comment. thank you very much.

Comment: yes it does, you were passing the bindings as the second argument to `statement` already ... np